# Date object in JSON schema

Tags: java, json, date, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I have my json schema for `createdAt` as

```
{
  "title": "details",
  "definitions": {
    "dateTime": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
  "properties" : {
    "createdAt": { "$ref": "#/definitions/dateTime" }
  }
}
```

and when I try to create Object

```
Details details = ImmutableDetails.builder()
         .createdAt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
           .parse("2021-11-30T00:22:11.454Z"))
         .build();
```

I am getting the error as

```
createDate: [Nov 30, 2021, 0:22:11 AM] is not a valid date-time. 
Expected [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,9}Z, 
          yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[+-]HH:mm, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[0-9]{1,9}[+-]HH:mm]
```

How do I specify my JSON schema to accept `java.util.Date` object ?

Comment: Please try new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") instead of new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"). JSON schema does not like the Z at the end of the date-time

Comment: I am unable to parse `2021-11-30T00:22:11.454Z` using the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: I recommend that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Exactly how to do instead I cannot tell since I don’t know your `ImmutableDetails` and its builder. But do look into [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: A [mre], please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "date-time" format in JSON Schema follows [RFC3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339).  That's timestamps that look like `2021-12-31T23:59:59Z` or `2021-12-31T23:59:59-05:30`, which is exactly what the error message says.

You're already starting out with timestamps in the correct format, and then converting them to an unacceptable format -- so just remove that part.

Comment: My `Details` Class has field `createdAt` of type `Date`. If I remove the conversion I cannot pass String to Details Builder.

Comment: @Logic I recommend you do not use `Date`. That class too is poorly designed and long outdated. Use `Instant` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If that requires passing an `Instant` to your builder, do so: `.createdAt(Instant.parse("2021-11-30T00:22:11.454Z"))`. Yes, it is this simple.